# Cascading Dropdown / Combo box in SharePoint List

Tags: 2010, list, calculated-column

I want to create a custom drop down combo box, which should show information based on selection of previous combo box. Just like we can do it in Excel.

However, I do not want to do any coding in the form back-end. Or rather, I cannot with no access to back-end or SharePoint designer.

Is this achievable via usage of formulas in a SharePoint list?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be done in [InfoPath](http://basquang.wordpress.com/2010/03/29/cascading-drop-down-list-in-sharepoint-2010-using-infopath-2010/) or via [SPServices](http://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=%24%28%29.SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns&referringTitle=Documentation). You are looking for cascading dropdown functionality.

You can do the SPServcies route by embedding a web part onto the page (the old ?pageView=Shared&ToolpaneView=2 query string parameter trick) and reference jQuery and SPServices from a local document library.

Comment: Right, I am looking for Cascading Dropdown functionality. I should have added that I do not have knowledge of creating forms in Infopath at the moment, and I only have Infopath 2007 which does not seem to work for SP2010.

Comment: As for SPServices, I do not have access to the back end and hence will not be able to edit the code to be able to add the hierarchy effect.

Comment: SPServices is a jquery library, no backend server access is required.

Comment: I do not have access to the site using SharePoint Designer, which means I cannot edit any code and that is what I meant when I said "backend". Sorry if this confused you.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a hierarchical term set instead.  I have done this with few different sites and it seems to work well in many circumstances.  Also, if you need to be able to see multiple layers rather then just the end point then you can choose to display the full path of the term set.

Comment: I will check the feasibility, thanks for the idea.

Answer (score 0):

SPServices can be used in a Content Editor Web Part or an HTML Form Web Part on the page, there is no need to use SharePoint Designer. There are lots of resources online that will show you how to do so.

Answer (score -1):

You can actually open up new item/edit item forms in a text editor.   No access or special software required.

Comment: Thanks for your contribution! Unfortunately this is not in line with the OP's question. Please consider revising it to answer the original question instead.